# Using txfonts with Polish characters breaks tables

Tags: fonts, tables

### Restated Problem and a Solution

The use of a times font using the package `txfonts` will cause tables to be improperly displayed (see below for an image) if a character such as ę,ą or a different character with an ogonek is used.

This has something to do with the procedure involved not being local, that is, having unwanted side effects elsewhere.

An effective way of keeping whatever is done local is by enclosing it in brackets `{ę}`. This can be generally invoked for any mention of the character in question by mapping `ę` to `{ę}`, `a` to `{ą}` and so on in the preamble by the following:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter {281}{{ę}} % 281 is the decimal utf-8 code of ę
...
```

This will solve the problem for the whole document

*A more general solution still that fixes the error introduced in the source file of `txfonts` is described below under the heading WORKAROUND. However, if you do not want to fiddle with the way the package is called (possibly because it is called in a stylesheet you do not want to change) redefining the characters is a good solution*

### Initial question

I am typesetting a multilingual document with `pdflatex` (MikTeX, all packages up to date). I need to use Times font, and, for the time being, I cannot switch to LuaLatex or XeLatex since I am in the final phase of typesetting a book with a class provided by my publisher and I would need to adjust my code in order to use these above.

Using Polish characters with `txfonts` causes the tables to crash:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[polish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\newcommand{\ee}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontencoding{T1}}
\newcommand{\pl}{\selectlanguage{polish}\fontencoding{T1}}
\begin{document}
\textbf{A minimal example using a times font}
As soon as I enter the Polish character \pl ę  \ee the tables crash 
(the lines of the table get printed onto each other).
\begin{table}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|}
\hline
type&n    &rel        \\
\hline
\hline
One line in the table &260& many  \\
Another line in the table      &792&49  \\
A third line in the table       &288&1  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}\caption{A test table.}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The alternative package `mathptmx` does not cause this problem; however, it does not provide the Greek characters I need. This is demonstrated in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,polish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}       
\newcommand{\ee}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontencoding{T1}}
\newcommand{\grrk}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}\fontencoding{LGR}}
\begin{document}
\textbf{A minimal example using a times font}
I need to  print polytonic Greek (and other special characters) using a 
times font (e.g. \grrk ἐᾶν \textbf{ἐᾶν})! \ee  
I use the \emph{txfonts} (or   \emph{txfontsb}) package,
the alternative \emph{mathptmx} cannot find the metric files (``Couldn't find `grtm.cfg'''). 
\end{document}
```

How can I use `txfonts` and still prevent the tables from crashing? I have also tried out `txfontsb`!

Update: I see now the has nothing to do with Polish, it's the diacritic in ę (the *ogonek*) that causes the problem. The same problem appears in the following code with an ogonek on an m:

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{txfonts}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
    \begin{document}
    text with ogonek:        \k{m}  
    \begin{table}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|}
    \hline
    type&n    &rel        \\
    \hline
    \hline
    One line in the table &260& many  \\
    Another line &792&49  \\
    A third line in the table       &288&1  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\end{center}\caption{A test table.}\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

If `\k{m}` is enclosed in brackets `{\k{m}}` the tables work fine. So it has something to do with  locality and the way `txfonts` apply the ogonek.

Comment: No, I don't think that redefining characters is a good solution. It will break kerning and hyphenation, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest fix: use braces around ę:

```
\pl {ę} \ee
```

For longer text, you could use the `otherlanguage` environment instead of switching by `\selectlanguage` to Polish and back to English:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{polish}
ę
\end{otherlanguage}
```

Before, with `\pl ę  \ee` (`\selectlanguage`), for illustration:

[image: Polish text and table, problem]

Afterwards, with braces or `otherlanguage`:

[image: Polish text and table, fixed]

Comment: Thanks, that **does** work. However, this solution is extremely impractical. Normally, I don't even signal the change of language in any way, that is I write Polish characters as in Wałęsa without explicit switching. This worked fine with the old times package and with mathptmx. Is there any other way? What causes the tables to crash?

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels: I added a shorter fix by braces, which limits whatever the ę locally causes.

Comment: Thanks! I see now it has nothing to do with Polish, it's the diacritic in ę (the _ogonek_) that causes the problem. The same problem appears in the following code with an ogonek on an m:

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Now that the problem was reduced to the ogonek, I've found a workaround: I map the unicode characters ę, ą and so on to an explicit composition of e, a plus ogonek and put these into brackets. In other words, adding
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter {281}{{\k{e}}}
to the preamble will solve my problem for the whole document. Thanks for your help that got me on the right track! I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: There's a tragic error in `txfonts.sty` (lines 1070-1072) where an `\ooalign` is not brace protected. This makes `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` global as soon as one uses a letter with an ogonek.

Comment: How can we tell the relevant people to fix it or, indeed, fix it ourselves?

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels See my edited answer: no `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or braces are necessary, when you precede `\usepackage{txfonts}` with the magic code I show. Unfortunately the package `txfonts` seems to have been unmaintained since a long time.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea to say `\selectlanguage{<language>}` in the middle of a paragraph, as this command does many things with unpredictable results in case of a page break and, as you experienced, also in other cases.

For short inserts in a different language, use

```
\foreignlanguage{polish}{ę}
```

while for longer passages you can choose between

```
\begin{otherlanguage*}{polish}
...
\end{otherlanguage*}
```

and

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{polish}
...
\end{otherlanguage}
```

The difference is that the former doesn't change the fixed words (the chapter's name and so on), while the latter does. Both change the settings for hyphenation and language shortcuts.

It's actually not necessary to write `\foreignlanguage{polish}{<polish passage>}`:

```
\newcommand{\pl}[1]{\foreignlanguage{polish}{#1}}
```

makes available the syntax `\pl{polish passage}`.

## Workaround

There is a tragic error in `txfonts.sty` where `\k` is redefined in a wrong way: the `\ooalign` macro is not protected by braces and so, as soon as one uses a letter with an ogonek at the outer group level, the setting `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` becomes global.

One can correct it with

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\T@n@@nc@d@ngM@cr@M@d\relax}
\makeatother
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

This will avoid the wrong redefinition, so no other trick is necessary, as the definition of `\k` will remain the correct one issued by the fontenc package. However, a better loading order would be

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\T@n@@nc@d@ngM@cr@M@d\relax}
\makeatother
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

A possible cleaner solution might be to write a "corrected package", say `fixtxfonts.sty` that says

```
\ProvidesPackage{fixtxfonts}
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \let\T@n@@nc@d@ngM@cr@M@d\relax
  \DeclareTextCommand{\k}{LY1}[1]{{\ooalign{\hidewidth\char7\crcr#1}}}%
}
\RequirePackage{txfonts}
```

and say `\usepackage{fixtxfonts}` instead of `\usepackage{txfonts}`

Comment: Thanks; however, I need to swith languages constantly, this is why I actually normally do not switch them explicitely or only wiht minimal tags. The T1 font encoding is most of the time good enough for me. It would be very cumbersome to edit the whole manuscript for language switches.

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels An error made since a long time doesn't become good. Sorry. I don't see any advantage in writing `english \pl polish \ee english` instead of `english \pl{polish} english`.

Comment: Of course you're right and I will keep this in mind in the future! However, I normally do not switch at all, that is, I write hallo cześć привет and so on. And being able to do this is very valuable to me.

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels This will give wrong hyphenations.

Comment: I know :-) but I live with that (but again, you're right, it's just laziness!)

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels See edited message for a probably resolutive workaround.